# Spring Application Context Oracle Cache

Tags: java, xml, spring, oracle, caching

I have a problem with the sync between oracle database and my spring web application .
I'm able to insert in the database from my application back-office but when i try to add a row in the database and then adding an insert from my application i get a constraint error because the id already exist .

So i think that's a caching problem

This is my application Context xml file

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="myurl" /> 
    <property name="user" value="myuser"/> 
    <property name="password" value="mypass"/> 
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: I think that's not a caching problem. Maybe I am wrong. Can you elaborately describe the insert process of your application(with source code)? What you mean by  "i try to add a row in the database and then adding an insert from my application".

Comment: I add a row manually in the database then when I return to my application and try to persist a new object. I get a constraint error (because my application doesn't get the new values inserted in the database).

Comment: how are you incrementing your primary key? I am drawing a possible scenario. Maybe when you insert a row in the database there will be an increment of primary key. But from application you are not getting the increment and trying to insert data in the same row.

Comment: i'm using sequence generator type .. it's a cache problem i'm sure ...i disabled the second level cache and i tried to flush and refresh the entity manager but the data source pool first cache still enabled

Comment: I don't think connection caching at dataSource does contain data related information. It mainly contains authentication information of the connection. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/concache.htm#CDEHJDJF. Can you provide the query you are manually executing in the database and the source code of your entity.